# Revolution slider activation issue

Tags: wordpress, slider

I am facing a problem with Revolution Slider activation. When I try to activate  Revolution Slider a blank area is shown with no error and plugin cannot be activated.Can anyone help me to activate this slider.

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  This is a premium plugin so contact plugin support and ask them for help.

Comment: try setting wp debug to true

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that you didn't activate the plugin on any other website if it is activated on any other website using the same purchase code first deactivate it from another website then activate it on your website using the purchase code.

Sometimes it didn't activate due to some server issues.